# Solve the following system of linear ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$$x'_{1}=x_{1}-x_{3}$$

$$x'_{2}=4x_{1}-3x_{2}-x_{3}$$

$$x'_{3}=x_{1}+x_{3}$$

What i tried

I first convert it to a system of 3x3 matrix

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
4 & -3 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then i compute out the eigenvalue by forming the characteristic polynomial

$(1-{\lambda})({-3-\lambda})(1-{\lambda})=0$

Solving gives

${\lambda}=1$,${\lambda}=-3$ and ${\lambda}=2$ for the eigenvalue. It is from this part onward that im stuck.

I know i need to find eigenvectors, so i substitute each eigenvalue into the

characteristic polynomial say for ${\lambda}=0$, i got

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
4 & -3 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I know i have to solve the following system of equations to get the eigenvector, but im unsure of how to proceed. Could anyone please explain. Thanks

Comment: You went from: $(1- \lambda)(1- \lambda)(-3- \lambda)=0$ to $\lambda =0$?

Comment: Sorry should be $1$

Comment: ...so then you shouldn't solve $AX=0$, but $(A-I)X=0$.

Comment: Note also that the $x_1,x_3$ subsystem is isolated from $x_2$, so you could solve this 2-dimensional system first. This then shows you that you got the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues wrong. There is a complex pair of conjugate eigenvalues.

Comment: Do i have to find the inverse of each matrix $A$ for each eigenvalue in order to solve the systems of equations?

Comment: You can solve it by changing $A-I$ to it's row reduced Echelon form.